# What to do with browsers that are zoomed in and not displaying pages properly?

Tags: browser

I'm creating websites with an audience spanning from early 30s to late Post-War era and I had to consider testing to IE8 for these veteran users. It's a headache but this can be done. The only problem now are those (very few) users who has a default settings of zoomed-in browsers. The problem occurred when I showed my older boss the website that I did and it is displayed incorrectly. Of course they can just zoom-out but you need to tell them this. Their argument was what if other clients has the same settings and no one tells them that they are actually looking at a zoomed-in version of the page.

So is there:

1. An automatic script that can zoom in browsers automatically to normal state?
2. Tell the user to zoom-out normally if the user is zoomed-in
3. Best solution to this problem.

I know one of the founders of Github actually has a solution but it is said on his page that  [it's not currently usable for desktop](http://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/)

Comment: I develop web sites that must be usable on MSIE 8 to 11, Firefox and Chrome. You now, If the page is zoomed it will appear bigger. Apart from this, it must work, else you have a bug in your markup/css that must be fixed. Perhaps you should be specific about your problem, to have suggestion about fixing your bugs,